# What triggers the CAPTCHA when posting an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, captcha, answers

I've recently wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131228/674039) and the system challenged with a CAPTCHA before I could post.  These are pretty annoying and slow me down, because I am scarcely better than a robot at reading the darn things!

It is not the first time this has happened for me and I would like to write in a style which avoids triggering those checks - so, are they random checks?  Are they content related?  What triggers them and how can I write in a style which is less likely to trigger the challenges?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide has the information you're looking for

Comment: @StevenV I don't think that answer is accurate. I asked one single question on SO this morning after having been idle for a day and received a captcha popup. And if it is, then I found a bug/additional use case :)

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't answer my question.  That was the first and only answer I've posted so far today, and it still triggered the captcha - so it can't be rate limiting.  I suspect it's due to some content related heuristics.

Comment: I know what you mean about them being hard. CAPTCHA is getting so hard it defeats the point of using it now. I've actually given up on forms after 4/5 failed attempts at a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @StevenV - I also had this experience.... one answer and a pop-up.... something changed

Comment: Did you take less than 5 seconds to answer?

Comment: You must have pasted formatted code and clicked "Post your answer" with 5 seconds. Generally it happens with me, if I do it.

Comment: @Will yes, I generally compose my answers in a different text editor (where I have autocompletion etc ..) and then just paste the completed answer into the web page.

Comment: I had it happen when pasting right before submit also. In my case, I wrote a comment that started looking more like an answer, pasted it over and got hit with the captcha.

Comment: Today I got hit by an even more annoying version of this.  I posted a question and got "An error has occurred...", so I went back and tried again, it hit me with the Captcha, which then responded "An error has occurred...".  I logged out, logged in and retried the post, Captcha again, but this time it actually posted the question.

Comment: @WIll Depends if you're blind or not (I noticed the audio one, but it's even worse...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering with too much content too quickly seems to trigger the captcha for me.

Occasionally I use sublime text to write up my answers, and when I paste a large amount of content into the answer field and submit it usually triggers a captcha.

Beyond that, I don't know any of the details on what metrics are used to determine when a captcha is shown, and I honestly think that this is a case where it would be important to not know the specifics so that spammers can't game the system.

Comment: This is what happened to me on reflection, I wrote code in LinqPad and pasted in about 20 lines of code.

Comment: I get the captcha pretty consistently on my posts and this answer seems to be the case for me.  Generally, I code up a solution in VS to test my idea then copy/paste into an answer with details. This always seems to ping me as a robot, even if I spend a significant amount of time editing the post.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect it has something to do with IP addresses too.

I got my first one this morning, answering a question on the train, on an Android tablet. I certainly didn't answer within 5 seconds of starting the answer, but I quite likely disconnected and reconnected between starting the answer and submitting it. So it could well have been triggered by a change in IP address.

On the other hand, it's also possible that I submitted within 5 seconds of reconnecting... so perhaps that triggered it.

I really should get out less.

Answer (score 4):

I get a CAPTCHA (usually the check box, but I have gotten the other type) pretty reliably when I have been sitting on a post for too long before posting it. It happens more often on questions (due to my habit of hoarding  question drafts), but I think that it has happened when posting answers too.

I don't know the reasoning or mechanics behind this, but I felt it's worthwhile to mention given how reliably this produces a CAPTCHA.

Comment: They must think bots like to loiter in drafts.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Complete Rate Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

> ### Answering
>
> Users > 125 < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
>
> Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds