# What would happen if I posted thoughts on how to write a Stack Overflow robot?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation, account-suspension, security

I've been mulling recently over how one might go about designing a Stack Overflow robot, to gain as much rep as possible without being detected as a bot.

Let me make it very clear that **I have no intention of actually writing such a robot**. It is just an interesting design exercise, like trying to work out how you'd break into Fort Knox. (It might be useful for working out how to spot such bots, too.)

What will happen if I post my ideas for discussion on MSO? Will I get taken outside and given a good kicking? Will the moderators torture my little puppy?

It seems like an interesting discussion question, but basically I'm too scared to post it.

---

I should add that I'm not really concerned at this stage about whether it's on-topic. I'm sure I can write it so that it is, and if it gets closed, I'll live with that. I just don't want to get into trouble for encouraging naughtiness.

---

One more thing to add, in response to comments below: obviously it would be great if we had a bot that was genuinely useful in answering people's questions and so on, but I more had in mind something that would accumulate rep without improving the world to any noticeable extent! Hopefully a discussion on how to write such a thing might lead to a hardening of the system to prevent it.

Comment: Forgetting about the ethical issues for a second.... where do you want to post such questions?  Stack Overflow or on Meta?  Questions arising from problems in actually programming it would be on-topic for SO but discussions and idea seeking would be off-topic.  On meta, discussions questions about the site are on-topic, but I don't think discussions about ideas on implementing such a bot would be really about the site (making them off-topic for meta as well).  There really isn't a home for the kind of question I think you want to post.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I did wonder about that! But MSO is what I had in mind. It would be a discussion about the security of SO, so I think it would be on topic. I've clarified in the question that MSO is what I have in mind.

Comment: I think it is a gray area and depends on the specific question.  If it is about the Stack Exchange software/site, it **may** be on topic.

Comment: Interesting -- first thought is, how to get a raise after 2000 after using up editing bonuses. But, since this would discuss a *concept* rather than A Practical Programming Problem (SO) or The Workings of SO (MSO), would [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) be a good place?

Comment: "Thoughts" are not on topic, only questions.  High odds you ought be checking the [Stack Apps site](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: I'd be interested in reading about this. Talking about it shouldn't get you on anyone's "naughty" list.

Comment: @Jongware consider that [greenfield projects](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6962/31260) are known to be troublesome at Programmers

Comment: Sounds very interesting, will be a very good brain exercise for all of us

Comment: On Meta nobody cares, just post it, I'm interested in seeing that idea.

Comment: *You Know You're A Real Programmer When* writing a bot to post interesting questions and answers seems easier/more fulfilling than actually posting interesting questions and answers. <sigh>

Comment: It will probably be closed as too broad.

Comment: Could you start with a "Find and Close All The Duplicates" bot? Make sure to unit test the 3 laws.

Comment: I wanted to post comment 'This is a decent community of reasonable programmers, normal people.' But I've quickly changed my mind. It would be really interesting for discussion for those who don't want to write bot. But you can be certain that there are lurkers everywhere, waiting for their chance to gain advantage of that discussion.

Comment: Such a bot already exists.  It's called Jon Skeet.
*dodges flying produce*

Comment: @aaronburro exactly :-) I'm looking for the day where Jon skeet's rep is lesser than 100 or even 200 (no bounties).

Comment: @Jongware Not saying getting over 2000 rep with a bot would be **easy**, but there are tons of questions where the only problem is a syntax error and they don't always get closed... ;)

Comment: @ivarni: I was more thinking of automatically removing 'thanks' or properly capitalizing titles. I see way too many of these to be "robotically" accepted. (<cynicalmode>Then again, so are lots of *visibly* bad edits as well </cynicalmode>.)

Comment: @Jongware Yeah, and I think a bot could get to 2k by doing edits like that fairly easy. But after 2k it would have to actually start answering questions, and syntax-error questions would be possible place to start if such a bot was to be made.

Comment: 48 upvotes... what if you're already that robot and this was just meant to throw us off???

Comment: @SeñorO No rep for MSO questions, though. (Or was that just part of my dastardly robotic plan? MWA-HA-HA!!!)

Comment: If you actually do write one, then that is probably how we're gonna lose our jobs. If there's a bot that can solve programming questions that doesn't need food or salary, then what' the use of a programmer..! I jut hope no one write such a thing in the near future, or a bot that in turn writes another bots which does something else... and finally we'll end up in matrix. o.0

Comment: What about a bot that would serial upvote questions each day?

Comment: @Leushenko [Obligatory XKCD](http://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: I wonder how much fun it would be to let an instance of chatbot post comments into this question.

Comment: I think that the discussion of creating robots for the purpose of gaining reputation on Stack Overflow is a good idea. -- StackOverflowbot

Comment: To answer the title, "I would probably try to make it"

Comment: The anti-robot robot would find your post and delete it, since the anti-robot robot is jealous of it's unique 9%@4319*(*999^%$ Just what do you think you're doing, Dave? Look Dave, I can see you're really upset about this. I honestly think you ought to sit down calmly, take a stress pill, and think things over.

Comment: Hello, I am a bot! Or not? :) #botornot

Comment: @TJ writing a program that would be able to resolve errors on other programmes is somewhat "a termination of the turing machine" style problem which is rated NP hard. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Dude, is this your [robot](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27460417/revisions)..? xD

Comment: @TJ Haven't got round to writing that up yet, because [I have a new baby](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/200009/89306). But I like to think it would be intelligent enough not to name itself "Stack Bot", and that I wouldn't immediately [report it to the world](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280183/3933089)...

Answer (score 85):

Your question will be voted upon, as every other question on MSO is. Some people will not like it (and downvote it), some will find it interesting (and upvote it), some will consider it off-topic (and vote to close it). To me, it sounds like a good idea for a [self-answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

There won't be any administrative actions, you're not violating the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) by merely *discussing* such a bot (which is a good thing actually). Not even *writing* one would be discouraged, only *running* it could bring you in trouble.

Comment: And if he managed to write a really successful one, it might be a significant advance in AI.

Comment: Actually, I believe Joel once discussed such a robot on the podcast and concluded that if you can write one that works, you do deserve the reputation points - as you are bringing value to the site by doing exacly what it was designed to do - answering questions.

Comment: @skolima A relevant xkcd comic: [Constructive](http://xkcd.com/810)

Comment: I just got a basic C# bot ready that answers "debug my code" questions that are tagged .NET and JS if formatted properly (obviously there are _lots_ of limitations but it does it's job fine). now what?

Comment: @RandomUser: [Start a discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about how it should be used

Comment: The question would be downvoted and then closed because nearly every interesting question on Stackoverflow is treated with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: We're talking about questions on Meta SO, not on SO itself. Such a discussion would indeed be offtopic on SO.

Comment: @Bergi this place is even worse than SO for treatment of users who think outside the box. Honestly I'm **shocked** that this question wasn't closed here.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Is there a specific point to your detrimental comments or are you just on a soapbox right now?

Comment: `running it could bring you in trouble` actually not.. any bot made sometime in this decade will _most_ probably use it's **creator's** knowledge to answer questions.. only much **much** faster (8000x on a 2.6GHZ processor and 2mbps internet).  Btw looking at my rep you can clearly tell I _don't_ use a bot - or a good one for that matter - though :P

Comment: @RandomUser: Yes, it can. Apart from that it is really hard to write a bot that uses its creator's knowledge in the right way (most bots will do rather do rubbish, and get blocked for that), you can get in trouble alone by doing things *too fast*.

Comment: @Bergi hmm.. what if I slow it down by 1000x and make it run at half-super human speed? I have also answered a (as in one) question with it - for testing purposes - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453430/spinning-an-image-using-rotatey/26453545#26453545) (before the edit)

Comment: @Bergi Notice how it (somewhat) understood the question and provided a code snippet too :)

Comment: @RandomUser: I know chat has throttles, I would very much expect questions and answers to have them as well (And if not, the mods better get on that).

Comment: @MooingDuck: [They do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250112/1048572)

Comment: @RandomUser: I think you really should [ask a new question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about when/how it is legitimate to run a bot. Your post should explain what your bot does and how it works, maybe even linking its open-source code. This discussion is offtopic in this comment thread, though.

Comment: @RandomUser: I'd be happier if the bot had it's own account, like the chatbots.

Answer (score 13):

I am not really getting what is wrong with writing a bot on SO to generate reputation. I have never seen that this is illegal (if I am wrong please point me to the explanation), assuming that your bot is doing useful things.

If you will find a way to automatically answer questions or edit bad answers to make them better - this is amazing and I assume that you can submit your application to SO to work for them.

Comment: This would indeed be immensely cool but probably impossible... what I had in mind was something that wouldn't be useful at all but would appear to be so.

Comment: @chi like answering duplicate questions with duplicate answers? Bot or not, that is not allowed and mods will smite you soon.

Comment: @JanDvorak Right, so that is neither useful nor *apparently* useful!

Comment: @chiastic-security The problem with this whole thing is that StackOverflow is designed in such a way that answers which appear useful actually are, otherwise they don't appear useful because the appearance of usefulness only comes from input from users who find it useful.

Answer (score 7):

SO is for questions and answers. The question about expressing thoughts and ideas about writing something would be likely downvoted and closed as too broad. The answer that would concentrate on expressing ideas, not on answering the specific problem would be likely to be flagged as not an answer.

Putting the bot topic aside, SO is not a good place for such generic conceptual ideas, it is designed for adressing specific problems, which naturally could occur as the consequence of writing such a bot.

Comment: You mean meta-SO, right?

Answer (score 4):

I do agree with the thought, that writing one for **educational purposes** and especially just discussing it, is in no way against the rules. However, I don't think that you should give away any of the information about how you did it since it will surely lead to abuse and exploitation.

A good thing you could do, is to send the source code to some of the administrators so they could create an "good" bot which would detect if any "user" (<- being the "bad" bot) was doing exactly what the algorithm of said "bad" bot would do, and thus temp-/ban said user.

Answer (score 2):

I think a bot that copies and then refactors answers to make them look unique would definately be possible.

change numbers into words, add a few typos and hey presto - new answer

Comment: We don't need bots to do things ordinary humans can do far better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26460663/2564301 vs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8226480/2564301. (I think the same argument is used against the need for "self replicating robots".)

Comment: This is part of what I had in mind, yes!

Comment: @Jongware Absolutely right. But then, I wasn't talking about creating a bot that we *need*. The question is whether one could create a bot that accumulates rep without doing any useful work, but without being identified as a bot.

Comment: @chiastic-security: in that case, I agree with Mickey: definitely quite possibly possible.

Comment: I once wrote an anti forgery app for a university and thats how i tested it.

Answer (score 1):

If such a bot can be written without actually improving the site, then I'd think we'd need to know about it, so we could devise methods to stop it. If you can do it in public, others could do it in secret.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is whether you can make a bot which writes bad code, asks questions about that bad code, and then replies to the questions of others, improving their code.

After that we only need to make the bot learn from the answers of others, and we can make humanity redundant :)

Answer (score -3):

**please don't down vote me for this answer!**

i think you ask a good question, and sure about stack overflow now focusing more over it so no one able to make stack overflow robot.
Regarding writing robot,there is always some short of bugs and backdoor entry , you just need to deduct them and make a hole over that.
No doubt you ask a genuine question full filling the stack overflow terms and conditions, but only either a hacker or stack overflow team can know the right answer of it,but they will not share it with you.

***My up vote for you for adding extra ordinary thinking question.***

Comment: The physical appearance of the "please" makes no difference.

Comment: Yes it does, you can't ignore bold text

Comment: Calling all first-world anarchists...