# How does a question get so many upvotes so quickly?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637107/how-to-login-api-rest-laravel-from-mobile-app) had 3 upvotes within seconds even though it is too broad. How does that happen? It almost looks like a bot asked and upvoted.

Comment: Sometimes I've seen _robo-upvoters_, that upvote everything coming in from low-rep users. I don't believe the OP actually has created a sock-puppet, but who knows?

Comment: "I'd like to know that too ... +1"

Comment: Either way, the meta effect seems to have restored balance to the universe.

Comment: Something to add to my [SO bot design](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275354/what-would-happen-if-i-posted-thoughts-on-how-to-write-a-stack-overflow-robot)!

Comment: This is actually a dupe of a question I had (or contributed to) maybe 6 months back.  Sometimes it's out-and-out vote fraud, sometimes the OP tells his friends to vote for it (eg, in a chatroom), sometimes the question gets linked from an external site.  You also see questions violently downvoted similarly.

Comment: Strangely, the question was deleted by the author :)

Comment: It's in a super popular tag [tag:php], so it's not all that surprising.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you suspect voting fraud of some sort then you're more than welcome to flag the post in question and explain to the moderators what you suspect, and what basis you have for that suspicion.  They can investigate further with far more capable tools than you have access to.

That said, lots of people troll new questions looking for questions to answer, and many of them vote on the questions they see.  Getting several votes rather quickly is certainly not something that seems suspicious to me.

Comment: It doesn't seem suspicious on good questions, it does on broad ones. I hate to flag for mod attention because all it is a suspicion based on quality of question and rapidity of upvotes. I'd hate to send resources off on some, what may be, wild goose chase on something like this. I've never seen ti this blatantly before and I was just curious how it could have happened *so* quickly on such a low quality question. The Meta Effect seems to have corrected the issue on this question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard If you don't feel that your suspicion is worth being investigated, then by all means don't flag the content.  I see so much upvoting of crap in general that I don't suspect voting fraud just because a broad question is upvoted (without somewhat more compelling evidence), but as long as your flag is in good faith, it's not wrong to flag.

Comment: Cool @Servy, thank you. More compelling evidence? Heh. I guess I could have waited to see if more upvotes were coming.

Comment: To me more compelling would be a pattern of repeated unusual behavior over time, rather than a single slightly out of place behavior involving only a few users.  If you saw this same behavior several times in a row from what you suspect to be the same person then that would be something that, for me, would move beyond reasonable expectation and into "possible fraud" territory.

Comment: @JayBlanchard on a general note, _slippery_ posts (questions, answers) are often prone to "mad voting up", see [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: @Servy do you work for Stack Exchange?

Comment: @usr No, I do not.