# What triggers the CAPTCHA besides the rate-limiter?

Tags: support, captcha

I'm aware of these existing QAs:

- [What triggers the CAPTCHA when posting an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250112/what-triggers-the-captcha-when-posting-an-answer)
- [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

However both refer only to the Rate-limiter.

I recently switched my login from using Yahoo OpenId to using Google, since I did that switch I've started seeing the "Are you a robot?" CAPTCHA prompt fairly regularly, sometimes every time I post an answer on SO. I've also been abroad and visiting different places lately so my IP address range probably differs from my usual history, but now that I'm back home I'm still getting the prompts - but I always use the same browser, so my cookies and session data persist - I'd think a webapp would take cookies over IP address as a way of determining a user's identity.

I don't get an actual CAPTCHA, just the preliminary "Are you a robot?" question with the *Flight of the Conchords* photo and the ReCAPTCHA JavaScript checkbox - it always lets me proceed without any further Turing tests.

Assuming it is based on my changing IP addresses then there should be a way for users to selectively disable that security option - just like how you can tell your bank if you're going abroad so they don't unnecessarily flag transactions.

Comment: AFAIK it can also be triggered if you write your post too quickly (by copying and pasting) or too slowly (by typing up a draft, leaving the tab open for a day without touching the draft and then revising).

Comment: The bank comparison is totally off IMHO. The transaction flagging is for _your_ safety. The CAPTCHA is for the safety of the site so scripts don't post and mess up everything.